# How to make a build arg mandatory during Docker build?

Tags: docker

Is there any way to make a build argument mandatory during `docker build`? The expected behaviour would be for the build to fail if the argument is missing.

For example, for the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

ARG MY_VARIABLE
ENV MY_VARIABLE $MY_VARIABLE

RUN ...
```

I would like the build to fail at `ARG MY_VARIABLE` when built with `docker build -t my-tag .` and pass when built with `docker build -t my-tag --build-arg MY_VARIABLE=my_value .`.

Is there any way to achieve that behaviour? Setting a default value doesn't really do the trick in my case.

(I'm running Docker `1.11.1` on `darwin/amd64`.)

**EDIT**:
One way of doing that I can think of is to run a command that fails when `MY_VARIABLE` is empty, e.g.:

```
FROM ubuntu

ARG MY_VARIABLE
RUN test -n "$MY_VARIABLE"
ENV MY_VARIABLE $MY_VARIABLE

RUN ...
```

but it doesn't seem to be a very idiomatic solution to the problem at hand.

Comment: It is a little odd that it will fail if an arg is passed that isn't defined but not the other way around, but that seems to be the way it works. You could run a "test.sh" script as late-stage step in your dockerfile that checks for a range of conditions and handles them appropriately. Depending on the complexity, it may be easier to manage as a separate file. If it's just one or two ARGs, your in-line method may in fact be the best.

Comment: @konradstrack have you considered accepting an answer? :)

Answer (score 70):

I tested with `RUN test -n <ARGvariablename>` what @konradstrack mentioned in the original (edit) post... that seems do the job of mandating the variable to be passed as the build time argument for the `docker build` command:

```
FROM ubuntu

ARG MY_VARIABLE
RUN test -n "$MY_VARIABLE"
ENV MY_VARIABLE $MY_VARIABLE
```

Comment: Note you do need the quotes because `test -n ` does not fail but `test -n ""` does

Comment: What if I want to use the ARG in the FROM statement? E.g. to select the base image to be used? If I declare it before the FROM then yeah it works, but the ARG gets wiped at the FROM statement and then I cannot verify that something was passed in like this.

Answer (score 45):

Another simple way:

```
RUN test -n "$MY_VARIABLE" || (echo "MY_VARIABLE  not set" && false)
```

Comment: This seems like the most explicit to me

Answer (score 42):

You can also use [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to achieve this.

Let's say your mandatory build argument is called  `MANDATORY_BUILD_ARGUMENT`, and you want it to be set and non-empty, your Dockerfile could look like this:

```sh
    FROM debian:stretch-slim
    MAINTAINER Evel Knievel <evel@kniev.el>
    
    ARG MANDATORY_BUILD_ARGUMENT
    
    RUN \
    # Check for mandatory build arguments
        : "${MANDATORY_BUILD_ARGUMENT:?Build argument needs to be set and non-empty.}" \
    
    # Install libraries
    &&  apt-get update \
    &&  apt-get install -y \
            cowsay \
            fortune \

    # Cleanup
    &&  apt-get clean \
    &&  rm -rf \
            /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
            /var/tmp/* \
            /tmp/* \

    CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/games/fortune | /usr/games/cowsay"]
```

Of course, you would also want to use the build-argument for something, unlike I did, but still, I recommend building this Dockerfile and taking it for a test-run :)

#### EDIT

As mentioned in [@Jeffrey Wen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51271572/3406709), to make sure that this errors out on a `centos:7` image (and possibly others, I admittedly haven't tested this on other images than `stretch-slim`):

> Ensure that you're executing the RUN command with the bash shell.
>
> `RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", ": ${MYUID:?Build argument needs to be set and not null.}"]`

Comment: This doesn't echo the value of the argument to the shell so it's better for secrets, like API tokens.

Comment: To understand the why/how, see [here](https://superuser.com/a/423997/475652). Basically, the colon at the beginning says "ignore what's after me and return success", because when the argument has a value, we don't want to execute it. However, parameter expansion still runs prior to executing the entire command, which is how we get an error when a value is not given.

Answer (score 12):

Long time ago I had a need to introduce a required (mandatory) `ARG`, and for better UX include the check at the beginning:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
ARG MY_ARG
RUN [ -z "$MY_ARG" ] && echo "MY_ARG is required" && exit 1 || true

...

RUN ./use-my-arg.sh
```

But **this busts the build cache for every single layer** after the initial `MY_ARG`, because `MY_ARG=VALUE` is prepended to every `RUN` command afterwards.

Whenever I changed `MY_ARG` it would end up rebuilding the whole image, instead of rerunning the last `RUN` command only.

To bring caching back, I have changed my build to a multi-staged one:

- The first stage uses `MY_ARG` and checks it's presence.
- The second stage proceeds as usual and declares `ARG MY_ARG` right at the end.

```
FROM alpine:3.11.5
ARG MY_ARG
RUN [ -z "$MY_ARG" ] && echo "MY_ARG is required" && exit 1 || true

FROM ubuntu:bionic
...
ARG MY_ARG
RUN ./use-my-arg.sh
```

Since `ARG MY_ARG` in the second stage is declared right *before* it's used, all the previous steps in that stage are unaffected, thus cache properly.

Comment: Sadly, this won't work with BuildKit because such a stage checking required build args will be skipped altogether.

Comment: @N1ngu, what about adding a dependency on the first stage? Making it a true multi-stage build. You can `COPY --from` some extremely small file just to build the graph.

Answer (score 9):

You could do something like this...

```
 FROM ubuntu:14.04
 ONBUILD ARG MY_VARIABLE
 ONBUILD RUN if [ -z "$MY_VARIABLE" ]; then echo "NOT SET - ERROR"; exit 1; else : ; fi
```

Then `docker build -t my_variable_base .`

Then build your images based on this...

```
FROM my_variable_base
...
```

It's not *super* clean, but at least it abstracts the 'bleh' stuff away to the base image.

Comment: That doesn't work when using `ONBUID`, only when I remove them.

Answer (score 8):

I cannot comment yet because I do not have 50 reputation, but I would like to add onto @Jan Nash's solution because I had a little difficulty getting it to work with my image.

If you copy/paste @Jan Nash's solution, it will work and spit out the error message that the build argument is not specified.

**What I want to add**

When I tried getting it to work on a CentOS 7 image (centos:7), Docker ran the `RUN` command **without** erroring out.

**Solution**

Ensure that you're executing the `RUN` command with the bash shell.

`RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", ": ${MYUID:?Build argument needs to be set and not null.}"]`

I hope that helps for future incoming people. Otherwise, I believe @Jan Nash's solution is just brilliant.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that addition, I hope it's ok with you that I edited it into my answer (credited you ofc :)

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody is looking for a the solution but with `docker compose build`, I used mandatory variables.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  my-service:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - ENVVAR=${ENVVAR:?See build instructions}
```

After running `docker compose build`:

- Before exporting ENVVAR: **Invalid template: "required variable ENVVAR is missing a value: See build instructions"**
- After exporting ENVVAR: *build proceeds*

[Support for Required Environment variables](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4493)
[Compose Environment Variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers worked for me. I wanted `${MY_VARIABLE:?}` but did not want to print anything, so I did like this:

```
ARG MY_VARIABLE
RUN test -n ${MY_VARIABLE:?}
```

Nothing is printed on success. On error you see this, which is a good enough error:

> ERROR RUN test -n ${MY_VARIABLE:?}
> /bin/sh: MY_VARIABLE: parameter not set or null
> executor failed running [/bin/sh -c test -n ${MY_VARIABLE:?}]: >exit code: 2

Comment: The command can be anything and the colon is optional so it's possible to shorten that to `RUN true ${MY_VARIABLE?}`.